# Mouse events not working in OS X (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have `NSOpenGLView`

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MainOpenGLView : NSOpenGLView <NSWindowDelegate, NSSharingServiceDelegate, NSSharingServicePickerDelegate> 
@end
```

.m

```
#import "MainOpenGLView.h"
@implementation MainOpenGLView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    return self;
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSLog(@"mouse down");

}
@end
```

And mouseDown method is not working. All others mouse events too. What am I doing wrong?